# Can I set a custom sound that will notify me when I copy or paste text?

Tags: windows-10, audio, copy-paste, notifications

I am on Windows 10 and I want to set sound notification for copy and paste action. I tried using Shutter, but that program doesn't have that option.

Comment: You can use a program like AutoHotKey to play an audio file every time you use Ctrl+C or Ctrl+V.

Comment: Can you show me how to write for  Ctrl+C or Crtl+V because i only found for one button only.

Comment: I posted an answer for you. Good luck.

Comment: Just copy and paste that script into a file with a .ahk extension, install autohotkey, and run the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're at all familiar with AutoHotKey, make this file:

```
^c::
Suspend, On
SendInput {Ctrl Down}{c Down}
Sleep 50
SendInput {c Up}{Ctrl Up}
SoundPlay, {absolute path to audio file}
Suspend, Off
Exit

^v::
Suspend, On
SendInput {Ctrl Down}{v Down}
Sleep 50
SendInput {v Up}{Ctrl Up}
SoundPlay, {absolute path to paste audio file}
Suspend, Off
Exit
```

It stops recursion by suspending hotkeys, and also plays the sound. After playing the sound, it resumes hotkey listening.

Comment: If you'd like an explanation I'd be happy to edit my answer and give a detailed explanation.

Comment: I can explain this. I found similary code on AutoHotkey forum but only for one key so i tried writing writing Ctrl + c and ^ + c but i didn't tried without +